# Creating a .cmd / .bat file or shortcut in Win10 that launches a remote VSCode environment within WSL2 Ubuntu

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This is what I want to call:

`"C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" --remote wsl+ubuntu /home/[username]/dev/bash/bash.code-workspace`

I can get a shortcut working by copying and pasting the above into the "New Shortcut" window. But when I open the shortcut, I get a blank console window that doesn't exit until I exit VS Code.

I'd really like to be able to do this in a script - either via `.cmd` or `.bat`. Or some other way that won't open a stray console window.

I've tried this:

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" "--remote wsl+ubuntu" "/home/[username]/dev/bash/bash.code-workspace"
```

But I get this error:

```
'C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a shortcut with :

```
"C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --remote wsl+ubuntu /home/[username]/dev/bash/bash.code-workspace
```